# Cannot get node server to proxy to nginx on RedHat Ec2 Instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy

I have a redhat Ec2 instance. And I have a simple Express App running on `port 3000`. I installed nginx and it is running correctly because I am able to proxy `s3` buckets static sites to other subdomains I am using. However, when I try and proxy my Express app to one of my subdomains I keep getting the nginx failure page. Here is my nginx config block I am using:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen      api.subdoamin.com:80;
    server_name  api.grouve.tech;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://00.000.00.000:3000;
            expires 1y;
            log_not_found off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
     error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Comment: are node and nginx running on the same instance?

Comment: Yes they are running on the same instance. My node app is running in /opt/api

Comment: you should then try using `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;`

Comment: proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000; did not work

Comment: Are there any `.conf` files in `/etc/nginx/default.d/`?

Comment: No .conf files in /etc/nginx/default.d/ and just fyi I am successfully proxying two s3 buckets to other subdomains.

Comment: If it is Centos or AmazonLinux, try running `sudo setenforce 0` from shell, then restart nginx

Comment: Damn pesky selinux that working!! Thanks @DusanBajic

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DusanBajic the answer is `sudo setenforce 0`

Comment: keep in mind that this fix will not survive a reboot, you need to disable selinux permanently ([fedora](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux-Disabling_SELinux.html), [centos](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html))